# Play console: new to Google play store app, are closed testing and open testing a must?

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services, google-play-console

I am new to mobile apps.  I am working on an app, have completed internal testing in Google play console.  I am wondering are closed and open testings required in order for the app to be released to public in Play Store?

I created an alpha release for closed testing, but testers were unable to install it:

```sh
App not available
A testing version of this app hasn't been published yet or isn't available for this account.
```

I saw the app status shows `in review`:

[image]

Is that the reason why testers were not able to install?

I created the test track/release on Saturday, usually how long it takes for Google to review the app/release?

Can I publish the app when closed testing is done? or I have to complete open testing?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you get what your paid for :-) I submitted ios app for review, it got reviewed in 24 hours.  For my android?  still waiting, today is 5th day now.  Apple's phone support works.  Google?  always error. Not to mention the forms to fill in app information is so much easier, simpler for ios.  Google's form are so complicated.

Comment: Also, I have the same problem after 2 days of Release it shows in the Review status please help us.